# Slonimsky Double Note Progressions

Tags: theory

What method did Slonimsky use to derive his Double Note Progressions? ... Starting on p.196 Double Notes Tritone progressions to p.214 Sesquitone (minor3th) progressions from (Thesaurus of Scale and Melody).

link to PDF: [Thesaurus of Scales and Melodic Patterns](http://www.lapetitedistribution.org/archive/Nicolas_Slonimsky.pdf)

Comment: It's just like the rest of the book: a selection of patterns, except here he's repeating each pattern up a tritone.